# Is mysql_real_escape_string() necessary when using prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

For this query, is necessary to use `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Any improvement or the query is fine ?

```
$consulta = $_REQUEST["term"]."%";

($sql = $db->prepare('select location from location_job where location like ?'));

$sql->bind_param('s', $consulta);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($location);

$data = array();

while ($sql->fetch()) {
    $data[] = array('label' => $location);
}
```

The query speed is important in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are PHP MySQLi prepared queries with bound parameters secure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561586/are-php-mysqli-prepared-queries-with-bound-parameters-secure)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, prepared queries (when used properly) will ensure data cannot change your SQL query and provide safe querying. You are using them properly, but you could make just one little change. Because you are using the '?' placeholder, it is easier to pass params through the execute method.

```
$sql->execute([$consulta]);
```

Just be careful if you're outputting that to your page, SQL parameter binding does not mean it will be safe for display within HTML, so run `htmlspecialchars()` on it as well when outputting.

Comment: so, something like this? $sql->bind_param('s'); $sql->execute(array($consulta));

Comment: Sorta, just loose the bind_param there and you should be good. All your doing is just binding your params when you go to call ->execute();

Comment: Not really, it's just the way to do it when you use the '?' placeholder. When you used named placeholders, you need to use ->bind_param(), for example: `$sql = $db->prepare('select location from location_job where location like :item')); $sql->bind_param(':item', $consulta);`

Comment: note that if you pass an array to execute after binding params, you'll have issues.  see this note on the php.net docs: http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#97531

Comment: One thing to note is that `execute()` can only take an array parameter when using the PDO extension. When using mysqli `execute()` has no parameters so you will need to use `bind_param()`.