# Should I use real_escape_string when using Prepared Statements?

Tags: php, security, mysqli, escaping, prepared-statement

The title says: should I use mysqli real_escape_string when using prepared statements?

Is it necessary, better for the security, overkill, doesn't make any sense, or...?

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232084/is-mysql-real-escape-string-necessary-when-using-prepared-statements

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "For data that will be inserted using placeholders": No. You'll end up double escaping the data (so you'll insert the escape sequences from `mysqli_real_escape_string` as data).

Comment: Strictly speaking, for the everything else mysqli_real_escape_string would be as useless as trim().