# PHP prepared statements ORDER BY not working

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm not sure either prepared statements are not capable of ordering data or I'm just bad at this, I've got this code:

```
$by_arrangement     = $_POST['filter_by_arrangement'];
$by_date            = $_POST['filter_by_date'];

$sql = "SELECT id,title,description,champion
        FROM our_videos
        WHERE datemade BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL ? DAY AND NOW()
        ORDER BY ?
        LIMIT 10";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $by_date, $by_arrangement);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $single_id, $single_title, $single_description, $single_champion);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
    //GETTING RESULTS
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Everything works perfect on arranging by date, though it's not working ORDER BY $by_arrangement,which can have following outcomes:

```
datemade DESC
datemade 
views DESC 
views 
comment_count DESC
comment_count
```

but it always orders by id for some reason... What could possibly be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You order by a colomn, which cannot be a binded variable.

I'll see if i can find a reference.

I have found this: [With mysqli and prepared statements can I PASS IN COLUMN NAMES to 'ORDER BY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618351/with-mysqli-and-prepared-statements-can-i-pass-in-column-names-to-order-by)

It contains an useful example for you.

Comment: *"I have found this: With mysqli and prepared statements can I PASS IN COLUMN NAMES to 'ORDER BY'"* - Which should have been marked as a duplicate. Including the one I used to close the question.