# PHP & mySQLi: Do I still need to check user input when using prepare statements?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, sql-injection, prepared-statement

If I'm using prepare statements in mySQLi, would I still need to escape or check user input in any way. So for example if I had the code:

```
$members = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "members");
$r_email = $_POST['r_email'];
$check = $members->prepare("select user_id from users where email = ?");
$check->bind_param('s', $r_email);
$check->execute();
$check->store_result();
if ($check->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "user already registered";
    $check->close();
}
$members->close();
```

Would I need to change `$r_email = $_POST['r_email']` to `$r_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['r_email']);`

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are PHP MySQLi prepared queries with bound parameters secure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561586/are-php-mysqli-prepared-queries-with-bound-parameters-secure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary to escape a value if you're going to pass as a parameter. In fact, you should not, because you'll insert literal backslashes into your data.

These must be part of the SQL query at prepare time, so the RDBMS can parse and validate them. or validate user input at form.

Always SQL-Escape data that you put in SQL sentences. Never SQL-Escape data outside SQL sentences.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to escape with prepared statements, but it's still a good idea to validate user input (eg. mandatory fields have been populated, numeric fields contain numeric values, etc)

Comment: Thanks for a simple, easy to understand answer, saved me from having to post a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

No need to escape input, but don't skimp on validation, you can still have logical errors like empty email being submitted, or a number of other side effects which could come back to bite you.

Always validate, keeps you sane later when bug testing, that's my motto @ least.