# MySQL prepared statements do I still need to use mysql_escape_string

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, prepared-statement

Do I still need to use mysql_escape_string to avoid SQL Injection attacks if I am using prepared statements in MySQL 5.3?

Comment: No, also this question is a duplicate of countless others

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are PHP MySQLi prepared queries with bound parameters secure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561586/are-php-mysqli-prepared-queries-with-bound-parameters-secure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDO should take care of the escaping/sanitizing for you. Assuming you mean:

```
$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = ?');
$db->execute(Array("bar's baz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat funny thing - you shouldn't use mysql_escape_string to avoid SQL Injection attacks even if you don't use prepared statements in MySQL 5.3.
Note that it is not "mysql_prevent_sql_injection()" function, it is **mysql escape string** one. So, it is used to escape strings. You have to escape strings despite of injection possibility. Yet it won't help with any query part other than quoted string.

Comment: I'm going to ask quite a difficult question.. Why?

Comment: Why would you escape a string if it's no longer a threat to your application? May be a silly question after all.

Comment: @Mave because escaping is required by syntax rules.